# Laravel tinymce data doesn't insert in database on server

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce-4

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and UniSharp/laravel-filemanager with TinyMCE. On my localhost it's working fine - no issues at all. But when try on server (shared hosting), some HTML tag not working - cannot insert to database(nothing happen).

This example is working - can insert to database:

```
<p><a href="http://url/file.pdf">yeye</a></p>
```

This example not working - can't insert to database(nothing happen):

```
<p><span style="color: blue;">blue</span></p>
```

Another not working example:

```
<p><video controls="controls" width="300" height="150">
<source src="http://url/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video></p>
```

Here is my laravel controller:

```
$content = request()->get('content');
$data->topicContent = $content;
$data->updated_by = $user;
$data->save();
```

`$content` is data from TinyMCE

Both server and localhost using PHP 5.6 and mySQL 5.6.38

Does anyone facing the same problem? How to solve this issue?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Request takes only data from input fields with "name" attributes!

Try to die and dump your request in controller like this:

```
dd($request->all());
```

and then add attribute `name="some_name"` and again

```
dd($request->all());
```